# Difference between ionic.io and ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I do not understand what are the difference between ionic.io and ionic framework ? Is it the same thing? So why is there two distinct websites and 2 names for the same product?

Answer (score 3):

Ionic framework is the framework for building hybrid mobile apps. It is, and always will be - **free**.

Ionic.io is the site for Ionic Platform, which adds additional services like Deploy, Build, Push notifications, User management, etc. It is currently in beta and it's thus free, but as they go live (soon, as far as I know) they will have [pricing](http://ionic.io/pricing) (there will be a free plan however).

Basically, you do not **need** Ionic Platform, but it's really awesome and worth the money (in case you fall out of the free tier) if you'll ask any Ionic developer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, I would say:

1. **Ionic framework** is both

   - A **CSS Framework** with a lot of reusable and customizable front-end UI elements.
   - A **JavaScript UI library** with JS components which give life to front-end elements
2. **Ionic.io** is the ecosystem which includes, among others:

   - Ionic Cloud
   - Ionic Creator
   - Ionic Lab
   - Ionic View

In this post, you can find more information:

https://solidgeargroup.com/hybrid-apps-development-with-ionic

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it:

- Ionic framework is an SDK
- Ionic.io is a platform and tooling

In other words, Ionic (framework) is a way to create mobile [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) hybrid apps based on Cordova, that let you leverage native phone features and also AngularJS's MVC-based approach to app development.  This is free.

Ionic.io, however, is a bunch of `web services and tools` that add value to your Ionic apps, letting you store stuff server-side, send push notifications, etc.  These may eventually cost money.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 websites deal with Ionic, but :

- Ionic.io is the main platform tool website where you can find all information about ionic "world" (Ionic Framework, Ionic platforms, Ionic icons, Ionic app creator, Forum...). It is the Tool Ionic showcase
- Ionic framework is useful for developers to know how to install and develop ionic apps.

I hope it helps